# How to parse Inner json objects arrays

Tags: android, parsing, json

I am working with the ESPN Sports API. Can any one help me how to parse this?

I am pasting my code, I am able to parse only the name and id–please help how to parse inner objects items.

```
public class BaseballActivity extends ListActivity{

private static String url = "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/baseball?apikey=h29yphwtf7893hktfbn7cd5g";

private static final String TAG_SPORTS = "sports";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_TIMESTAMP = "timestamp";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_NEWS = "news";
private static final String TAG_HEADLINES = "headlines";
private static final String TAG_LINKS = "links";
private static final String TAG_API = "api";
private static final String TAG_SPORTS1 = "sports";
private static final String TAG_HREF = "href";

JSONArray sports = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // HashMap for ListView

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> sportsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // creating Json parser instance
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // getting Json String from url

    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

    try{
        // Getting Array of Contacts
                    sports = json.getJSONArray(TAG_SPORTS);

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for(int i = 0; i < sports.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject c = sports.getJSONObject(i);


            //String news = c.getString(TAG_NEWS);
           // String headlines = c.getString(TAG_HEADLINES);
            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
           // String timestamp = c.getString(TAG_TIMESTAMP);
            String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);

         //   JSONObject links = c.getJSONObject(TAG_LINKS);
          //  JSONObject api = c.getJSONObject(TAG_API);
          //  JSONObject sports = c.getJSONObject(TAG_SPORTS1);

         //   String href = c.getString(TAG_HREF);



            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

         //  map.put(TAG_TIMESTAMP, timestamp);
            map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
           // map.put(TAG_NEWS, news);
           // map.put(TAG_HEADLINES, headlines);
            map.put(TAG_ID, id);
         //   map.put(TAG_HREF, href);
            sportsList.add(map);
         }
    }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();    

        }


    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, sportsList,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[]{TAG_NAME,TAG_ID} , new int[] {
            R.id.id,R.id.name});

   setListAdapter(adapter);   
 }
}
```

here is my link I am using

[Sample Link](http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/baseball?apikey=h29yphwtf7893hktfbn7cd5g)

Comment: What library are you using for the JSONParser?

Answer (score 1):

I would recomend you to use [gson](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/). For me it was much more easier to work with...

**EDIT: (some sample code)**

1. Download the gson-2.2.2.jar add it to your dependencies
2. Create a base class (when you use more than one request)

   ```
   public abstract class RequestBase {

   public String ToJson(){
       Gson gson = new Gson();
       return gson.toJson(this);
   }

   public abstract String getUrl();

   protected String getBaseUrl(){
       return //Your URL;
   }   
   }
   ```
3. Make a class which will execute your request..
4. Make classes for the requests and responses. Then you can just enter them with getters and setters:

   public class SomeRequest extends RequestBase {
       @SerializedName("Parameter1")
       private int Parameter1;

   ```
   public void setParameter1(int Parameter1) {
       this.Parameter1= Parameter1;
   }

   public int getParameter1() {
       return Parameter1;
   }

   @Override
   public String getUrl() {
       return this.getBaseUrl() +"YOUR/OWN/URL" + Parameter1;
   }
   }
   ```

and

```
public class SomeResponse {
@SerializedName("responseParameter1")
private int responseParameter1;

@SerializedName("responseParameter2")
private String responseParameter2;

public void setResponseParameter1(int responseParameter1) {
    this.responseParameter1= responseParameter1;
}

public int getResponseParameter1() {
    return responseParameter1;
}

public void setResponseParameter2(String responseParameter2) {
    this.responseParameter2= responseParameter2;
}

public String getResponseParameter1() {
    return responseParameter2;
}
}
```

Comment: @srikanth better? or do you wish more?

Comment: i am trying or please take a simple example like having three or four inner objects some with same name and with same items.as i was new to android.

Comment: @srikanth send me an email (email adress in my profile), then i will give you an more detailed example (tomorrow..) ist that okey for you?

Comment: i can see your website but where is your mail id.