# How to deserialize complex JSON-Objects from a WCF-Service in Android?

Tags: android, json, wcf, deserialization

I have a REST WCF Service that generate the following JSON.

```
{
   "RecordsUpdateResult":[
      {
         "ID":115,
         "Crud":2,
         "Data":{
            "__type":"Client:#PIT.Library.AndroidClasses",
            "ID":115,
            "Adress":"str. 1",
            "City":"Luzern",
            "Description":"Client 115",
            "PostalCode":6000
         }
      },
      {
         "ID":128,
         "Crud":2,
         "Data":{
            "__type":"Client:#PIT.Library.AndroidClasses",
            "ID":128,
            "Adress":"",
            "City":"",
            "Description":"Client 128",
            "PostalCode":0
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

How can I deserialize this on android phone with the gson library?

I suspect that the problem is the **"__type":"Client:#PIT.Library.AndroidClasses"**.
I have a class named "Client" on the Android side.

I would like to deserialize this JSON to the following class.

```
public class StammdatenUpdate extends ObjectBase
{
    @SerializedName("Crud")
    private CRUD    crud;
    @SerializedName("Data")
    private Object  data;

    @Override
    public String getSha1Hash()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public synchronized CRUD getCrud()
    {
        return crud;
    }

    public synchronized void setCrud(CRUD crud)
    {
        this.crud = crud;
    }

    public synchronized Object getData()
    {
        return data;
    }

    public synchronized void setData(Object data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

The property ID is in the base class.

```
    ...
    Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<StammdatenUpdate>>()
        {}.getType();
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

    // List<StammdatenUpdate> RecordsUpdate(StammdatenType type, Dictionary<long, string> listWithHashes)
    postData.setParameter(new String[] { "type", "listWithHashes" });
    postData.setValues(new String[] { gson.toJson(StammdatenType.CLIENT), gson.toJson(map) });

    String json = post.execute(postData);

    List<StammdatenUpdate> retValue = null;
    if(Tools.isNullOrEmpty(json) == false)
    {

        retValue = gson.fromJson(json, listType);
    }

    return retValue;
```

Comment: could the answer of this post be helpful for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197138/how-to-parse-inner-json-objects-arrays/12197186#12197186

Comment: Not really. I use gson, my classes have the attributes @SerializedName.

Comment: The answer is also for gson, and the example also have the attributes @SerializedName... can you also post the class where you are making the request and handle the response?

Comment: I've updated the code sample.

Comment: Why don't you use the gson library for the json in the request? that would be much easier and you wouldn't have any problems with the deserialisation..

Comment: What do you mean? I don't get it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17104/discussion-between-mr-s-and-geniali)

Answer (score 1):

Change the WCF annotation from:

BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.**Wrapped**

to:

BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.**WrappedRequest**

This change the JSON from:

```
   {
       "RecordsUpdateResult":[
          {
             "ID":115,
             "Crud":2,
             "Data":{
```

to:

```
[
          {
             "ID":115,
             "Crud":2,
             "Data":{
```

And the deserialization works fine.

```
    Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<StammdatenUpdate>>()
        {}.getType();
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

    List<StammdatenUpdate> retValue = null;
    if(Tools.isNullOrEmpty(json) == false)
    {
        retValue = gson.fromJson(json, listType);
    }

    return retValue;
```